Steel beam splice design
What is a good source of design recomendations for beam splices? I'm designing a structure and I need some help with getting proper splice strength for certain beam size. To make it simpler, I need tables or charts that define a bolted splice that is the same strength as the beam itself is.
https://support.tekla.com/doc/tekla-tedds/2023/rel_steel_beam_splice_design_en1993

Won't you need the load applied? not just the beam size...

@SolarMike, of course. I need to define the beams from the load, but then I need some pointers for proper splice, which are probably also standarized, so I don't need to loose time with detail of splice calculation. I'm not at most in my field and some help would be useful.

If you want the splice to have the same strength as the beam, the foolproof way is to connect the beam segments using full penetration butt weld all along the cut. Otherwise, you will need a professional engineer, not the design manual, which is useful only for those who know how.

I agree with you. I'm working in this way now: designing a functional structure and doing basic calculations. Then, I will discuss it with a structural engineer so that the details will be done correctly.

Glad to know you will consult with a structural engineer after your own effort. Good luck with your project.

You could try SteelConstruction.info. Find a link to SCI P398 "Moment Resisting Joints to EC3" near the bottom. This document should have worked examples etc. explaining how to do it.
If you're unsure about what you're doing (you mention you're "not at most in my field") I suggest you get a professional structural engineer to check your calculations once you're done.

Thanks. I will check this. After I'm done, as I said in my previous answer's comment, I will discuss it with a structural engineer.
